How to Implement a Carousel in Salesforce Commerce Cloud Using Business Manager
I am currently working on a project in Salesforce Commerce Cloud (SFCC) and need to implement a carousel on the homepage. I understand that SFCC encourages using content assets and slots for adding dynamic content to ISML templates.
Here is what I have done so far:
Placed necessary files:

slick.css
slick-theme.css
slick.min.js
in the static default folder
included paths of files in home.isml
Added carousel HTML to the content slot.

I am not able to see the carousel working on my homepage. I suspect that I might be missing some steps or configurations. Could someone provide detailed steps or best practices for implementing a carousel using Slick Slider in SFCC through Business Manager? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
